# How to testfor time with command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to `/testfor` time with command block in 1.8? Screenshots would be nice, if possible.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to do this yourself? Is a daylight sensor not viable for your specific problem? Why (i.e. describe what you want to achieve)? We are not a "build-your-command"-website, and we like to see people put effort into a question before putting effort into answers.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with [`/stats`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#stats) and [`/time`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#time).

First, you'll need to set up a scoreboard objective and an armor stand to store the time.

```
/scoreboard objectives add time dummy
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"time",Marker:1b,Invisible:1b}
/scoreboard players set #MATH time 24000
```

The third command here simply stores a value of 24000 in a fake player called `#MATH`, which we'll need later.

Set up a clock, such as a [fill clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227011/how-do-i-make-a-setblock-or-a-fill-clock), and have it run two commands:

```
/time query daytime
/scoreboard players operation @e[type=ArmorStand,name=time] time %= #MATH time
```

The second command makes it so that time resets to 0 after a full day, rather than keep going indefinitely.

Finally, stand on top of the `/time` command block and run

```
/stats block ~ ~-1 ~ set QueryResult @e[name=time,type=ArmorStand] time
```

You can now access the time in a target selector like any other scoreboard value, e.g.:

```
/testfor @e[type=ArmorStand,name=time,score_time=18000,score_time_min=18000]
```

to test for midnight.

Comment: The target for `/stats` can only resolve to **1** target, thus cannot be `@a` for a multiplayer environment. You could instead have it target a fake player (such as `/stats X Y Z set QueryResult #NAME time`) and use `/scoreboard players test #NAME time 18000 18000` to check the score. Alternatively, it could be set to a dummy entity like an armor stand, allowing you to use `/execute` and other commands off of it.

Comment: @Skylinerw Thanks, didn't know that. I changed it to use an invisible armor stand instead.

Comment: This is what i need thx bro!